# export data points from differential equation system?

Tags: export, differential-equations

I am solving a dynamical three equation system. Besides plotting the individual effects for each of the state variables in an array and in a tridimensional graph, I would like to export the data points to a .csv file. However, when I try to export the table to a .txt file via the "Export" command, the output is not suitable (as it exports the output in a very disorganized way). I was wondering if there could be a way to do this. The code I am using is below:

```
f = {L, \[Psi], d} /. NDSolve[{
  d'[t] == (1/z) (\[Alpha] - 
       X \[Beta] (d[t]/Y[t]) - \[Gamma] L[t] - \[Delta] \[Psi][
         t] - \[Tau] Y[t]) + \[Beta] (d[t]/Y[t]) d[t],
  L'[t] == j (Y[t]/K) - e,
  \[Psi]'[t] == p L[t] + 0.035 \[Psi][t],
  Y[t] == (I + E + \[Alpha] - 
      X \[Beta] ( d[t]/Y[t]) - \[Gamma] L[t] - \[Delta] \[Psi][
        t])/(1 - (1 - \[Tau]) (\[Psi][
          t] + (1 - s) (1 - \[Psi][t]) - m z)),
  L[0] == 0, \[Psi][0] == 0, 
  d[0] == 0} /. { \[Alpha] -> 1, \[Gamma] -> 10, \[Delta] -> 10, 
  X -> 1, \[Beta] -> 0.5, j -> 0.8, \[Tau] -> 0.01, I -> 1, 
  s -> 0.85, p -> 0.8, E -> 1, m -> 1.3, e -> 0.035, w -> 0.5, 
  z -> 1.2, K -> 1}, {L, \[Psi], d, Y}, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> 1000000 ][[1]]
l = {L[t], \[Psi][t], d[t]};
Show[GraphicsArray[Table[Plot[f[[i]][t], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All,
PlotStyle -> Blue,
AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {t, l[[i]]}, 
DisplayFunction -> Identity], {i, 3}]]]
Export["table.txt", f[t] /. sol, "Table"]
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Append[#[t] & /@ f, Red]], {t, 0, 200}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1,0.5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1500, AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ l]
```

Comment: Are you trying to export the actual points that NDSolve is using?

Comment: I HIGHLY caution against using variables such as `E` and `I` in *Mathematica*. These can have very bad side effects.

Comment: @kale ... because `E` and `I` are *definitely not variables* in *Mathematica*... ;)

Comment: @J.M. Ha. Hence the "HIGHLY" part.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Also, [your function is stiff](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7la6.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Result of `NDSolve` is an `InterpolatingFunction`, which is a Mathematica object, and is NOT a list of points. To export numerical list of points for any chosen step of **t**:

```
data1 = Table[Evaluate[f[[#]][t] & /@ {1, 2, 3}], {t, 0, 200, .1}];
Export["data1.csv", data1];
```

This creates data file "data1.csv" in default directory found by evaluating function **Directory[]**. The data file is now fine, it's easy to check:

```
data2 = Import["data1.csv"];

data1 === data2
```

> True

Choosing step **t** small enough will make your data smooth:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose@data2, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[Point[data2], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you everyone! I am getting my feet wet in Mathematica, and this forum is great for people trying to get familiar with the program. Have a great day!

Answer (score 5):

If you want the actual points NDSolve is using, you can extract that from the Interpolating functions.

```
    Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
    coords = Map[ First[InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[#]] &, f];
    output = MapThread[Transpose[{#1, #2@#1}] &, {coords, f}];
    ListPlot[output]
```

[image]

Comment: No need to load that package, even, since it's just a front end for hidden built-in functionality. `f["Coordinates"]` (where `f[]` is the `InterpolatingFunction[]` object) does the job.

Comment: Interesting.  Is that buried somewhere in the Mathematica documentation?  When I wanted to do something similar a while back I found http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html which lead me to the solution above

Comment: If you'll look at the contents of `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy.m`, you'll see how the exported functions map to hidden internal functionality of `InterpolatingFunction[]`.